# Wrapping text with tex-anchor: end

Tags: html, css, svg

So I have this HTML/CSS snippet:

HTML:

```
<svg class="container">
  <g>
    <svg class="amount-container">
      <text class="amount" >500</text>
     </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.amount {
  writing-mode: tb;
  text-anchor: end;
}

.amount-container {
  overflow: visible;
}

.container {
  background: white;
  margin: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy2p5ek0/)

Problem is I want the container svg ('.container') to increase its height to wrap the text ('.amount'). Any ideas how to fix it? I can't assign a fixed padding-top since the the text's length is not known beforehand.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your jsFiddle you've offset the text's `y` position. Can't you just give it an `x` and `y` position to keep it inside the container? EG: http://jsfiddle.net/jy2p5ek0/1/

Comment: It's not a "container" in SVG...it's essentially a "canvas/artboard" you place things on. Elements inside the SVG cannot affect the size of the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this automatically.  SVG does not have automatic layout like HTML.  You have to set its width and height, similar to the `<canvas>` element.

Your only option would be to use Javascript to detect the size of the text (by calling `getBBox()` on the text element) and altering the size of the SVG to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the attributes **x** and **y** to your text element to change the position. You could have, for example, something like this:

```
<text class="amount" x=10 y=5>5000</text>
```

And everything should work

Comment: For a particular text, yes it will work; but no for the general case.